# What does require('express')() do in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

As far as I understand, `require('express')()` doesn't create a server, it just bundles the functions together. But if so, how does the following code run without server?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Also, if it does create a server, why do I need to import `http` module and manually create a server in the following example?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I am very confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second example uses `http` because it also uses `socket.io` which requires an `http` server. You can instantiate such an http server with an express app, so that's what's being done

Comment: Doesn't the first example require http server?

Comment: It creates an HTTP protocol server from an express app, but it doesn't use `Server` from the `http` module for it, whereas the second example does (and needs to)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`require('express')()` creates an instance of an Express application.

It's short for this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
```

You don't need to explicitly use `http` if you want to create an HTTP server, because Express will create one for you if you call `app.listen()`.

If you need that server for something else, for instance, to attach a `socket.io` instance to, you can use this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(3000, ...); // returns an `http.Server` instance
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this eliminate the need of http for socket.io?

Comment: @SKG it eliminates the _explicit_ use of `http`, yes. Internally, Express does call `http.createServer()` to create the server.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you do `require('express')`, it imports a function. The following `()` calls the function as well. Basically it instantiates an express app.